# Application of multinomial theorem.

Tags: combinatorics

I need to find the coefficient of $x^5$ in $(x^5 +7x^3 +4x^2 +1)^3$

Now, my way of approaching this is looking in how many ways I can pick $x^5$ from each element available.

So I can get $x^5$ from picking $x^5$ as is, or by picking $x^3 * x^2$

then my answer would be:

$\binom{3}{1} + \binom{3}{1}*\binom{2}{1}$

Is my way of approaching this question correct? and how can I tackle it using the multinomial theorem?

thanks.

Comment: Well, you have to consider the coefficients.

Comment: would it be correct applying it this way?:
$\binom{3}{1,0,0,2} + \binom{3}{0,1,1,1}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$5 = 5 + 0 = 3 + 2$ these are the only two choices you have. So the answer would be ${3 \choose 1} + 7.4.{3\choose 1}{2\choose1}.$

Comment: Why do I have to take into concideration the scalers $7$ and $4$?

Comment: @vpam Because they are _there_ and don't disappear when multiplying. What is the coefficient of $x$ when you compute $(3x+4)^2$...? You can't ignore the $3$ and $4$.

Comment: @StackTD $24$. Thanks!